# Jcomments list and form not showing

Tags: joomla, comments, joomla-extensions

i have migrate my site joomla 1.5 to joomla 3.6.5. Jcomments working fine on joomla 1.5 but not working on joomla 3.6.5. Jcomments all configuration are same as old site extension but it's not showing anything in article full layout.

Plugin Configuration:
[image]

[image]

and this is link of article

http://www.weight-loss-center.net/joomlaL3/index.php/osteoporosis.html

Answer (score 0):

I have just post a reply on the forum post of JComments but for those who have a similar issue, about the comment list, it could be linked to multilingual. For instance, an article with /en/ on URL has some posts. If the site is multilingual and I access on my native language the URL would should /es/ on my browser and if no post in Spanish has been post, I won't see any comment.

Related to the form, I think is the template but as I answered in the forum post, I can see the form.